# Plotting Points on an IPA Chart

Tags: computational-linguistics, ipa

I would like to plot points on the "Consonants" and "Vowels" charts, as seen in the image below. I will extract each one separately, so they are individual images. Is there a way to make a coordinate system that will align to the image?

For example, the "Consonants" chart would be a 9x8 graph, and I could draw a point in "n" using (3,7).

I think it would be best to do this in R, but I am open to other solutions.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "plot points"? What are your x and y values?

Comment: I will need to create them. In the explanation, it's just using the cells of the IPA chart

Comment: As I understand it, this is a technical question about using R, not one about linguistics. I think what you want is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993189/overlay-data-onto-background-image-in-r

Comment: Thanks @JeremyNeedle. I just figured someone in linguistics may have done a similar task.